# Wrong value of UID in stat() and wrong pr_pid in psinfo_t

Tags: c++, c, unix, solaris, pid

My function reads process list from `/proc`, then read process `psinfo` file into proper sturcture, as well as data about this file, and prints it. 
The problem is, some of the data in those structures is wrong. As usual, the moment when program partially works, is the most confusing. It reads all data correct, except for PID (pr_pid), which is always 0, and UID of a file, which is also always 0. Why? Is it possible for data to load partially correctly? That shouldn't be possible.. 0 would be possible if we were talking about PPID, but solaris documentation clearly states pr_pid is the PID.
Links which I thought would have answers, but I couldn't find one:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1473/proc-4.html
http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam
http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

code:

```
void printProcessInformation(char pid[]){
    //find full path name to your "stat" file
    //DIR *dir;
    //struct dirent *ent;
    //Creating string with /proc/PID
    char * s = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s", "/proc/", pid) + 1);
    sprintf(s, "%s%s", "/proc/", pid);

    //Creating string with /proc/PID/psinfo (full path)
    char * fullPath = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s", s, "/psinfo") + 1);
    sprintf(fullPath, "%s%s", s, "/psinfo");
    free(s);
    //printf("%s\n",fullPath);
    //Reading data from file
    FILE* file = fopen(fullPath, "r");
    char* buffer;
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(psinfo_t));
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: Couldn't open file");
        return;
    }
    fread((void *)buffer, sizeof(psinfo_t), 1, file);
    psinfo_t* pData = (psinfo_t*) buffer;
    free(buffer);
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(stat));
    stat(file,buffer);
    struct stat* fileStat=(struct stat*) buffer;
    printf("File owner id:%d\n",fileStat->st_uid);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);
    struct passwd* pw=getpwuid(fileStat->st_uid);

    //Loading data from structures
    time_t sTime=pData->pr_start.tv_sec;
    int pr_pid=pData->pr_pid;
    char* fname=pData->pr_fname;
    char* uid=pw->pw_name;
    printf("%8s %5d %16s %.24s\n", uid, pr_pid, fname, ctime(&sTime));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
psinfo_t* pData = (psinfo_t*) buffer;
free(buffer);
 ...
int pr_pid=pData->pr_pid;
```

You're setting pData to the contents of buffer in the first line and then freeing it. What pData points to is now lost to you, it may in fact be reused in the next malloc. When you try to use it in the last line above you're reading who knows what. You're freeing too agressively in this case. Don't free pData, (indirectly through buffer) until you're done using it.

Comment: Yep. That, and I had another error, which I just found in stat, should have used `stat(fullPath,buffer);`

Comment: @Xyzk: Don't use the `struct stat` structure until you've verified that the `stat()` call worked.  Similarly with `fread()` — and `malloc()` too.  It is also not clear why you don't just create yourself `psinfo_t info;` and pass `&info` as the first argument to `fread()`.  That's saves the `malloc()` and `free()` and dispenses with ugly casting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "It is also not clear why you don't just create yourself psinfo_t info;" well, it's because I didn't think of it :) Will modify my code in a moment. The same about your other points. For some reason I stopped thinking about them as files.